# control permission to sites in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authorization, membership

I need to use custom authorization mechanism. Its very simple, uses database in which something like session is stored and checked if its active according to cookies. Nothing special. What is the best way to control permission to each side. Of course I can check in load event on each site if user is logged in but is there any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I Use ASP.NET Membership security model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440568/why-should-i-use-asp-net-membership-security-model)

Answer (score 5):

The built-in mechanism is [ASP .NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), which should fit basic needs out of the box. (If it does not you should try explaining why you cannot use it - there may be a solution).

Comment: You can also create your own provider classes for custom functionality if the default SQL Server based provider doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Agree.d  Check following link for a good tutorial: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx